# Microsoft Word Add-in 2013/2016 -- Detect File Tab Visible

Tags: ms-word, tabs, interop, add-in, ribbonx

I am developing a word add-in in C#. In word 2013/2016, the file tab takes up the whole document window and covers the editable text area. I need to know when the editable text region becomes no longer visible because the file menu is selected/visible. Some form of callback would be ideal, but a property would suffice.

I looked in the Application, Window, and Document objects for callbacks that indicate a file menu selection -- no success.

I looked for properties that indicate that the file menu is visible -- no success.

I looked for a callback or property that indicates that the editable area of the document is no longer visible -- no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also would not be opposed to some sort of Win32 solution. I tried monitoring a word document using SetWinEventHook(), but I was not able to find any way of detecting when the file menu was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The Backstage UI provides the `onShow` and `onHide` callbacks that allow to detect when the `File` tab is shown and hidden.

```
   <backstage onShow="OnShow">
```

Read more about that in the [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#odc_office14_ta_CustomizeBackstageView_performingActions) article.

Also you may find the [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: This project is a visual studio 2013-2016 VSTO project. Is there a way to configure the onShow and onHide callbacks for this type of project?